# How to make output filepaths relative?

Tags: css, path, compilation, less, codekit

Using Codekit 2.4, I want to specify a custom output filepath for a given Less file.

When I took over the project, the previous author's convention was set so that `/less/*.less` compiled to `/css/*.css`. However I changed the project settings so that the output folder set to the same folder as the source file (e.g. `/styles/*.less` compiles to `/styles/*.css`), with all files in the same directory. (This is just my workflow and I'm not here to discuss whether it's good practice to do so.)

For all my new less files under `/styles/`, this works as expected: all the `/styles/*.less` files compile to `/styles/*.css`. Now as I transfer code from the old Less files to the new ones, when I save the old Less files, CodeKit creates new CSS files in the same directory, per my specified project settings. I am happy to override the settings of each old Less file to compile to `../css/*.css`, as there aren't that many and they will eventually be deleted, but CodeKit does not give me the option to specify *relative* paths.

For example, when I click `/less/main.less` (an old file) in CodeKit, **"This file generates an output file"** is selected, and that output file is set to `/less/main.css`. I click the folder icon and use the filepicker to select `/css/main.css`, however the filename shown is

```
/Users/Chris/…/<repo-root>/css/main.css
```

Which is an absolute path. Further—and get this—when CodeKit compiles the file, it *treats* it as a relative path! So now the compiled output file is located at

```
/Users/Chris/…/<repo-root>/Users/Chris/…/<repo-root>/css/main.css
```

Now here's the part where I do my homework: I can override this behavior by going into `config.codekit` and manually changing the filepath, but this is only temporary and it resets every time I switch Git branches, which is, to say the least, annoying as hell.

How can I use CodeKit's filepicker to specify relative paths for output files? If I can't, how can I specify output paths without editing `config.codekit`?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to understand exactly what your desired directory structure looks like, but you can change the output paths for ALL Less files in a project by going to Project Settings > Languages > Less, adjusting the output path options, and then clicking the "apply" button in the top right corner of the output path section.

Those options allow you to specify relative paths from either the input Less file or the project's root folder.

As for the duplicated absolute paths: is this project on your local disk or on a remote volume?